# Windows 8.1 Search and Keyboard Navigation

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-search

When I press windows key, start typing, then end typing, I observe 2 waves of search results: one is instant, another one comes in about 0.5 seconds. I start typing, see my result on the 2-nd place, press down button to move the cursor button, then press enter to launch the item I want — very often before I press Enter the 2-nd wave of search results arrives, which resets the cursor, so I launch the 1st item instead of the 2nd one.

Is there some windows setting to resolve this issue? Like disable 2-nd wave of search results, or delay it for 2-3 seconds? I only started to suffer from this problem since 8.1 upgrade.

Comment: What are your current search settings like? Do you have the Bing online search enabled?

Comment: @techie007, it was enabled. However, disabling it has not affected the behavior I'm describing.

Comment: @techie007 I'm sorry it didn't help Soonts, but it helped me, thanks!